# How to enable visual styles without a manifest

Tags: c++, winapi, comctl32, visual-styles

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773187.aspx):

*"If you want your application to use ComCtl32.dll version 6, you must add an application manifest **or compiler directive** to specify that version 6 should be used if it is available."*

Notice the logical OR above? So what is this mysterious compiler directive?

I've got a native Win32 C++ application that is wholly contained in a single .cpp file. There are no resource files, manifest files, etc. I'd like to keep it that way, but I would also like to use visual styles.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can add this line to your stdafx.cpp for example:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Answer (score 34):

There's actually a third way with **no manifests whatsoever**, though it's rather hacky:

```
#include <windows.h>

// NOTE: It is recommended that you delay-load ComCtl32.dll (/DelayLoad:ComCtl32.dll)
// and that you ensure this code runs before GUI components are loaded.
// Otherwise, you may get weird issues, like black backgrounds in icons in image lists.
ULONG_PTR EnableVisualStyles(VOID)
{
    TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH];
    ULONG_PTR ulpActivationCookie = FALSE;
    ACTCTX actCtx =
    {
        sizeof(actCtx),
        ACTCTX_FLAG_RESOURCE_NAME_VALID
            | ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT
            | ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID,
        TEXT("shell32.dll"), 0, 0, dir, (LPCTSTR)124
    };
    UINT cch = GetSystemDirectory(dir, sizeof(dir) / sizeof(*dir));
    if (cch >= sizeof(dir) / sizeof(*dir)) { return FALSE; /*shouldn't happen*/ }
    dir[cch] = TEXT('\0');
    ActivateActCtx(CreateActCtx(&actCtx), &ulpActivationCookie);
    return ulpActivationCookie;
}
```

Comment: So this will break the day Microsoft changes the resource ID 124 to some other value in some future version of Windows.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Yes, hence why it's hacky.

Comment: I try this code in win10 but ActivateActCtx return 0 and last error show ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Comment: @herzlshemuelian the only possible invalid parameter would be the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateActCtx()`, which returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure. If `CreateActCtx()` fails, use `GetLastError()` to find out why (maybe the resource ID changed in Win10? This code works in Win7). Also, if `CreateActCtx()` succeeds, this code leaks the `HANDLE`. You need to call `ReleaseActCtx()` when you are finished using the activation context, but this code doesn't save the `HANDLE` anywhere.

Comment: It appears that CreateActCtx is always going to use a manifest at some point.  In this case, it's grabbing resource #124 from Shell32.dll, which happens to be a Manifest resource.  Between Windows XP and Windows 10, resource #124 has consistently been the manifest file.

Comment: Furthermore, using `CreateActCtx` is not "Hacky", it's what all Windows Forms programs use to enable visual styles.  It uses resource #101 (a manifest) from System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Comment: Wow, nevermind previous comment, it works like a charm! But it doesn't work with the tab controls, that isn't using new theme. what am I missing? https://imgur.com/EAQXIoz

Comment: @Jack: Not sure unfortunately.

Comment: Could someone explain what this code actually do?

Answer (score 9):

If you had kept reading, you would have found [the answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx):

> If you are using Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 or later, you can add the following compiler directive to your source code instead of manually creating a manifest. For readability, the directive is broken into two lines here.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' 
version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Comment: LOL, I did open that link, but skimmed right past that line. It looked like it was entirely about manifests.

Comment: The question (for OCD types) still remains over the above **instead of**: *If one has already included a manifest for other things, does the above still work?* A: If we read "manually creating a manifest" as "manually creating a manifest *specifically for this purpose*," yes.