# How to enable visual styles without a manifest

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am referring to this answer [How to enable visual styles without a manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308503/how-to-enable-visual-styles-without-a-manifest)

Doing what that answers says creates a `.manifest` and visual styles are enabled. However I don't want the manifest to be bounded with my .exe - I am delivering only my executable and would like everything bundled in there.

Is there a way to enable visual styles without manifest or maybe through embedding the manifest inside the executable itself?

Comment: I thought there was a facility for embedding the manifest in the executable so you don't need to copy the manifest file around manually... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Andre: wow great! can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Oh well, should have done that in the first place :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use mt.exe to embed the manifest into the executable as a resource.  This is a standard part of the build since VS2005, use a project template if you have trouble setting it up properly.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the end of stdafx.h file:

```
#if defined _M_IX86

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#elif defined _M_IA64

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#elif defined _M_X64

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#else

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#endif
```

Comment: This piece of code will create a .manifest and the executable will need it to enable visual styles. So if I move the executable somewhere else, I will lose visual styles.

Comment: Visual Studio embeds the manifest generated wuth this pragma with the default project settings.