# An XP style combobox in a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I need to create a combobox with an XP style IN a DLL with C++ and WIN32 API (no MFC).
I managed to create the control in the DLL (by not in XP style).
I managed to create XP style combobox in an exe with manifest, but it does not work in the DLL.

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about a DLL, it is just a chunk of code.  The manifest that enables visual styles needs to be present in the EXE.

Comment: @hans passant Actually that's not entire true. The manifest can also reside in the same directory as the executable - `filename.exe.manifest`

Comment: Answered here:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308503/how-to-enable-visual-styles-without-a-manifest.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your DLL to load comctl v6 (the DLL that provides "XP-themed" versions of the common controls) without relying on its hosting process to have the appropriate manifest, you need to make your DLL *isolation-aware*.

Either use the C++ class described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN, or try #defining `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED=1`.

Comment: Don't forget to add an appropriate manifest.  In this case, it would be id 3, I think.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830033 and http://www.gamedev.net/blog/802/entry-2154553-manifest-embedding-and-activation/

Answer (score 0):

In order to force your control to use XP themed rendering regardless if it's enabled in a manifest or not you will need to use visual styles API. This is available on XP and above and provides support for rendering most common controls. More information on using the API can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: To be precise: uxtheme.dll and its API is available on XP and above (WV,W7).