# Strange dll link dependency which cause "Error 0xc000007b"

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, win32gui

I'm developing a win32 app, and meet the problem of Error 0xc000007b when run Debug to bootstrap app. I've searched infomation about the error, and I found it maybe a x64 or x86 mismatch problem.

But in my project, there is no external dlls that need copy manually (which is the most common case for this error)，When I dive into details, I found strange deps stack for my exe.

The outlined blue file is genereted by project and is amd64 in DependenciesGUI ，When just look at the blue dll file (right part of the screenshot), it seems ok. But when I check the exe file (outlined red in left part of screenshot) which links the blue dll, the dll changes to depends on file `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.3636_none_a863d714867441db\comctl32.dll` and it is marked as i386.

I don't known which step is wrong? The whole project is generated with cmake to vs2022 C++17 like `cmake -B ../build/ -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64` and is all for x64. The exe is linked to lib by `target_link_libraries(${EXE_NAME} PRIVATE ${VIEWER_NAME})`, dll is linked like `target_link_libraries(${VIEWER_NAME} PRIVATE User32 Shell32 ComCtl32 ComDlg32 Gdi32 Msimg32 WinMM AdvAPI32 Ole32 ShLwApi Vfw32 WinInet)`.
[image]

Comment: 0xc000007b is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT so it's indeed a x86 vs x64 mismatch. The x86 common control dependency does seem strange. You should review your project check for things like that for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308532/403671 that would specify a hardcoded bitness

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for such a quick anwser, and as you guess, I find the wrong processorArchitecture in application manifests (should be arm64 but is x86), and it now works after I corrent it.

Comment: You should put "*" to make it work in all cases and answer yourself to get some points

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @Simon Mourier, I finally find the problem is that `processorArchitecture` in application manifests is configured as `x86` which should better be `*`. After I modified it correctly, the error got fixed.